# Angular Equal Ng-repeat Filter From StateParam

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have project that use to check detail page. When i use filter for filter it, i got problem. there are id from 1 until 10. if i filter with 1 it will be show 2 data. From data 1 and data 10.

I want if i filter with 1, only 1 showed. I've try this:

```
filter: {id: partyid}:true
```

But it can't. It can work if

```
filter: {id: 1}:true
```

partyid is from here:

```
$http.get('http://api.pemiluapi.org/partai/api/parties?apiKey=c6a0237499f3e4197546b5551a3a864f')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.parties = res.data;  
          $scope.partyid = $stateParams.partyId;

          //alert(res.data);              
        });
```

Comment: Could you provide a plunker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $stateParams.partyId is a string while you are filtering integer values with an exact comparator. 
The solution is to convert the partyId to integer:

```js
$scope.partyid = $stateParams.partyId * 1;
```